# How to fetch two column value in one colume based on boolean field

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, foreign-keys

I am working with SQL Server 2005.
I am having 3 table

**Product**

```
PId   |   PName
```

**Service**

```
SId   |   SName
```

**Bill**

```
BId   |   TypeId   |   IsService
```

TypeId is PId or SId. based on IsService Field.
If `IsService` is 1 then TypeId is SId and If `IsService` is 0 then TypeId is PId

I want to fetch PName and SName with Bill so how can I?

I am thinking of to Write stored Procedure for this..
and Adding Dynamic Column to Stored Procudure that column contain Either SName or PName as per IsService.

But don't know how to write this also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    Bill.*,
    CASE 
        WHEN Bill.IsService=1
        THEN Service.SName
        ELSE Product.PName
    END AS Name
FROM
    Bill
    LEFT JOIN Service
        ON Bill.TypeId=Service.SId
    LEFT JOIN Product
        ON Product.TypeId=Bill.BId
```

Comment: No problem... @Archana : remember to up vote the answer you think are good. That gives us all a warm fuzzy feeling :P

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    t.BId,
    tt.Name
FROM Bill t
Outer Apply
(
    SELECT PName AS name FROM Product   WHERE 0 = t.IsService AND PId = t.TypeId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SName AS name FROM Servicess WHERE 1 = t.IsService AND SId = t.TypeId
) tt
```